# Change the ArgoCD login and navbar icon

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, cicd, continuous-delivery, argocd

I am using version v2.4.3+471685f and I've made changes to the 'argocd-cm' configmap to update the ArgoCD icon by modifying my-styles.css as follows:

```
.my-styles.css: | 
   .nav-bar__logo img { 
      content: url(https://My-logo.png);
   }
```

However, the icon has not changed despite trying all the methods mentioned in the following links:[text](https://saumeya.github.io/4.custom-styles-argocd.html)
[text](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/3642#issuecomment-1118856816)
[text](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/3642#issuecomment-1373557471)

Answer (score 0):

In Argo CD v2.8.2+dbdfc71, I got it working by changing the following my [argocd-styles-cm](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/custom-styles/#argocd-styles-cm) config map:

```css
img.sidebar__logo__character {
    width: 60px !important;
    content: url("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2389292/264784405-1e7e5902-d48f-440d-98f4-44028f4bd90e.png") !important;
}
```

I got that exact `img.sidebar__logo__character` field by using the right click + inspect tool in firefox and testing there.
[image: screenshot of using the firefox inspect tool to check the name of the css class of the logo image in argocd]

After you update this config map, you may need to reload your argocd server pod, as config maps and secrets are only loaded into the a k8s pod at startup. You may also need to clear your cache and/or open a new tab.

Example of the full config map I'm using:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-styles-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  custom.styles.css: |
    .sidebar {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #414868, #232336);
      color: #c0caf5;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
    img.sidebar__logo__character {
       width: 60px !important;
       content: url("https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2389292/264784405-1e7e5902-d48f-440d-98f4-44028f4bd90e.png") !important;
    }
```

This assumes you have also set `ui.cssurl` in [argocd-cm](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/custom-styles/#argocd-cm_1):

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
  name: argocd-cm
data:
  ui.cssurl: "./custom/my-styles.css"
```

You also need to be make sure you have mounted that volume in your deployment:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  ...
spec:
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        ...
        - mountPath: /shared/app/custom
          name: styles
      ...
      volumes:
      ...
      - configMap:
          name: argocd-styles-cm
        name: styles
```

If you use the argocd helm chart, there is a [`configs.styles`](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/main/charts/argo-cd/values.yaml#L536-L544) parameter you can use and then you don't have to do the deployment volume mount.